# Module has no attribute Warp?

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo, gdal-python-binding

I'm using GDAL v2.14 on my Windows 10 machine. In that environment, I have two gdal python bindings. One is `import gdal`, the other is `import osgeo`. I installed Python's gdal using http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal.

On my Ubuntu server, there are two ways to install gdal. One is to do `sudo apt-get install python-gdal` and the other is `pip install gdal` (but you need the C headers for this install).

On my Windows install, I can use `gdal.Warp()` to warp a projection, or crop it. On Ubuntu, this fails with the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Warp'` on both "installations" of gdal. How can I make it cross-platform while also maintaining the same functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having was that my GDAL installation was version `1.11` (latest version on Ubuntu ppa due to the new major version) when my Windows installation was `2.1.4`. I fixed that using these steps:

Download GDAL's source using https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadSource. I picked `2.1.4`.
I then ran:

```
$ cd gdal-2.1.4/
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ cd swig/python/
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

It also turns out that `import gdal` and `from osgeo import gdal` are the same.